# Take value from one form and pass it to another one

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I am started to learn PLSQL Oracle and I tried to find a way to copy value from one form to another. 
I have two form, first `form (A)` make some calculation and in some case this calculation cannot be edited in form (A). 
I came in idea to make `form (B)` and pass this data from `form (A)` edit them, and pass it back to `form (A)`
Here is my code and picture of my idea.

```
begin
    set_block_property('POL',UPDATE_ALLOWED,PROPERTY_TRUE);

        update POL set  
        POLICA =: TENDER.POLICA,
        VOZAC = TENDER.VOZAC,
        BR_VOZACA = TENDER.BR_VOZACA,
    NEZGODA1 = TENDER.NEZGODA1,
        PUTNICI = TENDER.PUTNICI,
        BR_PUTNIKA = TENDER.BR_PUTNIKA,
        NEZGODA = TENDER.NEZGODA,
        AO_PLUS_LIMIT = TENDER.AO_PLUS_LIMIT,
        AO_PLUS_PREMIJA = TENDER.AOPLUSPREMIJA,
        PRAVNA_ZASTITA_LIMIT = TENDER.PRAVNA_ZASTITA_LIMIT,
        PRAVNA_ZASTITA_PREMIJA = TENDER.PRAVNA_ZASTITA_PREMIJA,
        LOM_STAKLA_PREMIJA = TENDER.LOM_STAKLA_PREMIJA,
        TROSKOVI_LIJECENJA = TENDER.TROSKOVI_LIJECENJA,
        TROSKOVI_LIJECENJA_PREMIJA = TENDER.TROSKOVI_LIJECENJA_PREMIJA

        WHERE POLICA =:TENDER.BRPOLICE;

end;
```

I try option: Copy Value from Item properties but I get error

```
FRM-30047: Cannot resolve item reference
```

I dont know where I made mistake? Any suggestion or comment ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms usually communicate via two following ways:

- parameter
- global variable

A global variable is simpler to use; in form A you simply set it to `:global.polica := :pol.polica;` and use it in form B as (for example)

```
select ...
from some_table
where polica = :global.polica;
```

**Global variables** are always *strings* (their datatype is `VARCHAR2`) whose size is restricted (that might depend on Forms version; I know that certain versions had it restricted to 255 characters).

A **parameter** is somewhat more complex to use, as you have to create it first (in Object Navigator's "Parameters" node), but it allows you to choose a datatype (so you aren't restricted to *strings* only). You set its value just like global variable's one: `:parameter.polica := :pol.polica;` but you have to actually *pass* it to form B within `CALL_FORM` (or `OPEN_FORM`) parameter list. For example:

A function which creates parameter list (will be used later in example):

```
function make_param_list (p_name in varchar2)
  return paramlist 
is
  pl_id     paramlist;
  w_button  number;
begin
  pl_id := get_parameter_list(p_name);
  if not id_null(pl_id) then
     destroy_parameter_list(pl_id);
  end if;

  pl_id := create_parameter_list(p_name);

  if id_null(pl_id) then
     message('DESIGN ERROR - PARAMLIST');
     if name_in('system.mode') <> 'QUERY' then
        raise form_trigger_failure;
     end if;
  else
     return pl_id;
  end if;
end;
```

Example; `list_id` is related to parameters we're talking about:

```
declare
  list_id ParamList;
begin
  list_id := make_param_list('input_params');

  Add_Parameter(list_id, 'ugo_id'         , TEXT_PARAMETER, :ugo.ugo_id);
  Add_Parameter(list_id, 'query_only_mode', TEXT_PARAMETER, :parameter.query_only_mode);

  call_form('ugoa', no_hide, no_replace, no_query_only, no_share_library_data, list_id);
end;
```

Much more info in Forms Online Help System.

Comment: Thank you for briefly explanation :)

Comment: Congratulations as being the first holder of `oracleforms` badge ever.

Comment: Thank you, @Barbaros (although it hasn't been awarded yet :))